# How to copy with GUI from command line on windows?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

Windows has `copy` in command line, but I want to launch the gui for it from CMD [like open this thing](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/0aa0d852-f51b-4afb-8568-2d334f98b692) when I start the transfer. How do I do this?

Comment: i know certain installers do this so it should be possible...

Answer (score 0):

CMD.exe does not provide this type of GUI.

PowerShell can, using the built-in cmdlets, specifically - Write-Progress.

[Write-Progress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-6)
Module:Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility

Example:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script

You can create progressbars in cmd.exe, but it requires really understanding how to.

See details here:
https://www.instructables.com/id/The-Amazing-Progress-Bar-in-CMD
https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1499

Or you use .HTA using VBScript to do it.
Example: 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/cbdd527c-f512-4e9f-bfbf-ed3933e638c3